# Error: cannot find symbol: method startActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am developing an application in order to connect to Google Navigator by the following code..

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public static void Call_GoogleMapsNavigation(int longitud,int latitud)
{
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +latitud+ ","+longitud+"")); 
Context.startActivity(i); 
}
```

... but I get the following error:

Error returned:

```
GWDCPSET_GlobalProcedures_MobileDevice.java:1223: cannot find symbol
symbol : method startActivity(android.content.Intent)
location: class antay.cfsatv30.wdgen.GWDCPSET_GlobalProcedures_MobileDevice
startActivity(i); 
^
```

I can not find the solution to the problem ...

Thank you very much,

Comment: Context does NOT have a public static method called startActivity() it is an instance method, please read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To explain a bit further the answer above.
What it means is that you can't/shouldn't not call statically `startActivity(intent).`

```
Context.startActivity(intent); //wrong notice capital 'C'
```

You need a Context instance.

So, the simplest thing to do, is add a parameter to your static method: 
**(Notice lowercase 'c' as a convention for method names in Java)**

```
public static void call_GoogleMapsNavigation(final Context context, int longitud,int latitud) { 

        ...
        context.startActivity(i); //right
}
```

So for example in your activity or any component in your app that holds a reference to a context instance, you call your method as follows

For simplicity I assume you call it from an activity(always holds a reference to a context):

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        <YourHelperClass>.callGoogleMapsNavigation(this, 23, 44); //static call
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
Context oContext;
oContext= mContext;
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + latitud+ "," + longitud));
oContext.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +latitud+ ","+longitud+""));`

`getContext.startActivity(i); //to get the context the method is called in`

Comment: Hey Ahmed, please could you provide some context and explanation with your answer.